# USB: Enable Trim (FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported)

Tags: usb, ssd, trim

First of all, I am pretty surprised my usb flash device supports trim:

```
sudo  hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep 'Model\|TRIM'
```

gives me:

```
Model Number:       SanDisk SSD CZ80 32GB                   
   *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
   *    Deterministic read data after TRIM
```

The usb stick is formatted with ext4. So according to hdparm, trim should work.
However when I switch to the device and run:

```
sudo fstrim ./
```

it gives me:

```
fstrim: ./: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported
```

So what could be the issue here? Does hdparm lie about trim support, or could there be an other issue? Who to ask to debug such issues?
(Info: fstrim works very well with my internal ssd).

Full output of `hdparm -I /dev/sdb` can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6944144/

Comment: only ext4 supports trim so what is the current formatting of the usb disc?

Comment: you are wrong: btrfs also supports trim. Apart from that I have stated "The usb stick is formatted with ext4"

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there are software problems with trim on usb

[Trim and SSD with usb 3.0 enclosure does not work - UASP not supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262154/trim-and-ssd-with-usb-3-0-enclosure-does-not-work-uasp-not-supported)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1336541