# SSD features (rotational/discard) not detected properly via USB

Tags: usb, ssd, btrfs, sata, trim

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Thinkpad W520, with kernel 4.10.0-20-generic (hwe-edge). I have two SSD drives: a flash USB 3.0 stick, and a SATA Samsung 850 EVO SSD. When I connect them to USB (the flash stick directly, and the SSD inside an Orico 2.5" SATA3.0 HDD enclosure), the kernel detects them as rotational devices (lsblk -o name,rota shows 1, /sys/block/<device>/queue/rotational also).

When I connect the SSD directly via eSATA, it correctly detects rotational = 0.

How can I correct this when connecting via USB? This is important because e.g. BTRFS auto-enables some SSD-specific optimizations when it detects SSD drives, and the way it detects this is by querying the rotational property in sysfs. I could add my BTRFS partition to fstab and add the SSD option for BTRFS there, but this sounds like a hack.

Also, the DISCARD capabilities of the SSD are not detected when it's connected via USB (lsblk -D shows 0 for DISC-GRAN and DISC-MAX).

Answer (score 0):

I have now stumbled upon this thread, where they explain that this happens because the USB-SATA controller does not support this. It seems that you have to get special SATA enclosures for SSDs.

[Trim and SSD with usb 3.0 enclosure does not work - UASP not supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262154/trim-and-ssd-with-usb-3-0-enclosure-does-not-work-uasp-not-supported)